# How to replace text without replacing the node property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

Suppose I've a HTML string

```
var _str = <div>The European languages are members of the same family. <div class="same">Their separate existence is a myth.</div> For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, <div class="same">their pronunciation and their most common words.</div></div>
```

I want to replace the text `same` to `<span class="highlighted">same</span>`

I was doing `_str.replace('same', '<span class="highlighted">same</span>');` so it is also replacing the `class="same"` to `class="<span class="highlighted">same</span>"`

Can anyone help me how to replace only text not anything inside the node ( <> )?

Comment: Could you not just add a space to either side of "same" in the replace and on the span? `_str.replace(' same ', '<span class="highlighted"> same </span>');`

Comment: @JamieBarker What if the word is followed by punctuation? `"we are the same."`

Comment: Just give a space before 'same' as _str.replace(' same', ' <span class="highlighted">same</span>');

Comment: Really, this is an issue with using Regular Expressions against HTML. You should parse `_str` into a HTML structure, then replace the word `same` at each individual node

Comment: @RGraham I'd like to do that but how will I know that the string I'm replacing is not inside any HTML tag ie. `<same>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
_str.replace(/([^"])same([^"])/g, '$1<span class="highlighted">same</span>$2');
```

As you noted, this solution is limited to this particular string. If you want to replace only the text between the HTML tags, parsing the HTML will be the safest option.

Comment: Solution works perfect but again it has a limitation. What if I'm searching for `class` in the string. Then the result will be `<div <span class="highlighted">class</span>="same">`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add a whitespace before 'same', like this:

```
_str.replace(' same', ' <span class="highlighted">same</span>');
```

Comment: This will be ignored in case of the text `<div>same example</div>`. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, it will be ignored.